# How can I figure out what this Python code does?

Tags: python

I am learning Python and I'd like to know what this code does.

```
# This code is supposed to get an input of a word and not a sentence
def do_something(word):
  index = len(word)/2
  len_word = len(word)
  if index == 0:
     return True
  elif len_word % 2 == 0:
      return word[0:index] == word[-1:index-1:-1]
  else:
      return word[0:index+1] == word[-1:index-1:-1]
```

Now I tried to check but the variable index doesn't work to me maybe because I am using 3.7.

But I checked it without using the variable and just counting it and I think this code suppose to check if the first half is equal to the second half backwards or something like that.

And I am also not sure why there is this line:

```
if index == 0:
 return True
```

Would someone explain it?

Comment: Try `len(word) // 2` for integer division in 3.x.

Comment: @shnap. The **function** in your script is checking whether _word_ is a **palindrome** where _word_ is a string. If _word_ is a string the function returns `True` otherwise it returns `False`

Comment: not super relevant but you can also rewrite the function as `def do_something(word): return word[0:ceil(len(word)/2)] == word[-1:len(word)//2-1:-1]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code defines a function. The function does not run. It is apparently intended to check if it's a palindrome

If you ran the function it would return a `boolean` value of `True` or `False` based on the word.

`index` is defined as `len(word)/2` (or `len(word)//2` as mentioned in the comments) so it is apparently intended to catch the case where `word` is something like `""`

The next elif checks if `word` is of even length. The code to check for a palindrome needs to be adjusted based on this. Hence the slight difference in return codes between the `elif` and `else`

`return word[0:index] == word[-1:index-1:-1]` (from the `elif` as an example) gets the first half of the word as `word[0:index]` and the second half *in reverse* by `word[-1:index-1:-1]` to check if they are identical. It reverses the second half of the word with that `-1` at the end of the slicing.

Answer (score 0):

```
  if index == 0: 
     return True
```

Checks if the input is only 1 word. Like `1//2 == 0` but 2 or more is not equals to 0.

```
elif len_word % 2 == 0:
      return word[0:index] == word[-1:index-1:-1] # will return True or False
```

If the length is even(2,4,6...) then compare characters of the string from `0 to index` with characters of the string from the end till `index-1 and if matches`return True`otherwise`False`

```
return word[0:index+1] == word[-1:index-1:-1]
```

If the length is odd(1,3,5...) then compare characters of the string from `0 to index+1` with characters of the string from the end till `index-1 and if matches`return True`otherwise`False`.

Note: there is a mistake in the code `index = len(word)/2` should have been with double slash `index = len(word)//2`. One slash is float dividing and will return 0.5 so the first case will never be true(index == 0).